# Gulp hook before 'cordova build xxx'

Tags: cordova, gulp, cordova-cli

I have my `gulpfile.js` with some tasks and I want to execute one task when I do `cordova build`

I created a `before_build` folder inside of the `hooks` folder with a simple `console.log("a")`in a js file.

But whe I run for example `cordova build android` it says `'console' is undefined`, I have to do something else to run Javascript? I couldn´t find more info.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I added `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of my .js file and the `console.log`  works but now I want to do `gulp myTask` and is throwing to me `gulp is not defined`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run it without leaving Node by pasting this code into the file `before_build/010_compile_css.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var gulp = require('gulp');
var path  = require('path');

var rootdir = process.argv[2];
var gulpfile = path.join(rootdir, 'gulpfile.js');

process.stdout.write('Compiling SCSS');

require(gulpfile);

//interaction
gulp.start('scss');
```

Comment: Will gulp.start() complete synchronously as Cordova hooks require?

Comment: I found that gulp.start() is deprecated and scheduled to be removed:
  https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/505  .. Though that was a year ago!

Comment: Latest Cordova no longer recommending using hooks folder, it will be deprecated soon. Please use JS method instead as per suggest by @David Douglas

Answer (score 5):

I found I had to use `__dirname` to require the 'gulpfile.js' file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = function(context) {
  var Q = context.requireCordovaModule('q');
  var deferral = new Q.defer();

  var path = require('path'),
      gulp = require('gulp'),
      gulpfile = path.join(__dirname, 'gulpfile');
  require(gulpfile);

  gulp.start('myTask').once('task_stop', function(){
      console.log('myTask done');
      deferral.resolve();
  });

  return deferral.promise;
}
```

NB: The 'gulpfile.js' and 'hook.js' are in same directory here. You can set custom path to hook js file in Cordova's **config.xml** file:

```
<hook type="before_build" src="app/hook.js" />
```

Comment: Also beware that Cordova hook scripts act from the root project directory so you may run into file path issues if your gulpfile.js operates from within a sub-directory.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I could run the command, here is my .js file inside `hooks/before_build`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("gulp", puts);
```

Comment: not the best solution since you're creating a new process from node to run another node script (gulp).

Comment: @AlexStack so, what do you think it's a better solution?